# Regular expression to cut digits

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a text of type:

`You have a new code: 12345678
Validity of the code: 20 minutes`

what regular expression would cut only the numbers between words `code:` and `Validity`? I need to extract the code.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. It should work in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Use `\d+`, don't use the `g`lobal flag. It will grab the first sequence of digits it encounters, which should be the code.

Comment: 2 seconds! I needed 2 seconds! XD

Comment: Welp, you provided the JS code, that explains the 2 seconds gap  ;)

Answer (score 0):

`/\d+/` should do it. If you just use `string.exec(/\d+/)` you'll get back just the first match.